Asm: terminal is spamming strings and not stopping at the inputs
Code:
section .bss
    choice resb 4         ; Buffer for storing user choice
    ans resb 32


section .text    
global _start

_start:



loop:
    ;welcome msg
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text1 
    mov rdx, text1_len
    syscall

    ;menu
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, c1
    mov rdx, c1_len
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, c2
    mov rdx, c2_len
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, c3
    mov rdx, c3_len
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, c4
    mov rdx, c4_len
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, c5
    mov rdx, c5_len
    syscall

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text2
    mov rdx, text2_len
    syscall

    ;gets choice
    mov rax, 0 
    mov rdi, 0 
    mov rsi, choice 
    mov rdx, 4
    syscall

    ;ends code there (i just wanted to test if it worked before i move on)
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall



section .data
    text1 db "Hello welcome to math help", 0xA
    c1 db "(1) Add", 0xA
    c2 db "(2) Subtract", 0xA
    c3 db "(3) Multiply", 0xA
    c4 db "(4) Divide", 0xA
    c5 db "(0) Exit", 0xA
    text2 db "Please enter your choice below", 0xA
    text1_len equ $ - text1
    c1_len equ $ - c1
    c2_len equ $ - c2
    c3_len equ $ - c3
    c4_len equ $ - c4
    c5_len equ $ - c5
    text2_len equ $ - text2

Terminal:
Hello welcome to math help
(1) Add
(2) Subtract
(3) Multiply
(4) Divide
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
(1) Add
(2) Subtract
(3) Multiply
(4) Divide
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
(2) Subtract
(3) Multiply
(4) Divide
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
(3) Multiply
(4) Divide
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
(4) Divide
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
(0) Exit
Please enter your choice below
Please enter your choice below


There's no question here.

Your XXX_len variables are not correct. c1_len is the length of all the menu items, not just c1. c2_len contains all the menu items starting from c2, and so on.

@Barmar: Well spotted, yeah duplicate of In NASM labels next to each other in memory are printing both strings instead of first one . I'd been looking for a loop using RCX as the loop counter or something since it's clobbered by syscall.  But apparently "spamming" didn't mean a loop, just extra output and still only one read call.  (OP: strace would have revealed that easily, that all this printing happened before the first read.  Also, one multi-line write would be a lot simpler!)

Not to mention that there's no jump instruction that could be causing repetition.

@Barmar: Well yeah, once I'd read through the whole code looking for one without seeing one, I realized that first guess was wrong. :P
